# Testing a component that uses useEffect using Enzyme shallow and not mount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

```
// MyComponent.jsx
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { fetchSomeData } = props;

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchSomeData();
  }, []);

  return (
    // Some other components here
  )
};

// MyComponent.react.test.jsx
...
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  test('useEffect', () => {
    const props = {
      fetchSomeData: jest.fn(),
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    // THIS DOES NOT WORK, HOW CAN I FIX IT?
    expect(props.fetchSomeData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When running the tests I get:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

The expect fails because `shallow` does not call useEffect. I cannot use mount because of other issues, need to find a way to make it work using `shallow`.

Answer (score 13):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) is not supported by [Enzyme's shallow rendering](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html). It is [on the roadmap](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/projects/4#card-20211476) (see column 'v16.8+: Hooks') to be fixed for the next version of Enzyme, as mentioned by [ljharb](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086#issuecomment-482777876)

What you're asking is not possible with the current setup. However, [a lot of people are struggling with this](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086).

I've solved / worked around this by:

- not using shallow rendering from Enzyme anymore
- use the [React Testing Library](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html#tools) instead of Enzyme
- mocking out modules via Jest

Here's a summary on how to mock modules, based on [Mock Modules](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#mocking-modules) from the React docs.

**contact.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Map from "./map";

function Contact(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Contact us via foo@bar.com
      </p>
      <Map center={props.center} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**contact.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

import Contact from "./contact";
import MockedMap from "./map";

jest.mock("./map", () => {
  return function DummyMap(props) {
    return (
      <p>A dummy map.</p>
    );
  };
});

it("should render contact information", () => {
  const center = { lat: 0, long: 0 };
  act(() => {
    render(
      <Contact
        name="Joni Baez"
        email="test@example.com"
        site="http://test.com"
        center={center}
      />,
      container
    );
  });
});
```

Useful resources:

- [React Testing Library docs - mocking](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-transition-group#mock)
- [React docs - Mocking Modules](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#mocking-modules)

Comment: Mocking out modules and using React Testing Library is a horrible way to go.  A ton of mocks is brittle, good luck with that.  We're now forced to test like Angular TestBed, and that's the most crappiest tests out there, full renders, it's just crap

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the useEffect issue the OP has

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution from a colleague of mine at CarbonFive:
https://blog.carbonfive.com/2019/08/05/shallow-testing-hooks-with-enzyme/

TL;DR: `jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(f => f())`

Comment: This useful but if you're using multiple useEffect's in a file then the order of useEffects in the component can impact the outcome of the test.

Comment: @TomPinchen -> [mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn) could be used for each one

Comment: again bad to mock all this stuff from the third party, this is a terrible way to write tests.

Comment: @PositiveGuy so what is the best way to mock useeffect, or to simulate how to users clicks and state is changed?

Comment: @PositiveGuy could you expand on your comment and explain what would be the alternative?

Comment: I use this approach and it works in most cases in various projects where you are limited to Enzyme shallow rendering. However, I get `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` exception every now and then.

Answer (score 3):

`shallow` doesn't run effect hooks in React by default (it works in mount though) but you could use `jest-react-hooks-shallow` to enable the useEffect and useLayoutEffect hooks while shallow mounting in enzyme.
Then testing is pretty straightforward and even your test specs will pass.
Here is a link to a article where testing the use-effect hook has been clearly tackled with shallow mounting in enzyme
https://medium.com/geekculture/testing-useeffect-and-redux-hooks-using-enzyme-4539ae3cb545
So basically with [jest-react-hooks-shallow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-react-hooks-shallow) for a component like

```
const ComponentWithHooks = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState<>();
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => setText(
    `Button clicked: ${buttonClicked.toString()}`), 
    [buttonClicked]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

you'd write tests like

```js
test('Renders default message and updates it on clicking a button', () => {
  const component = shallow(<App />);

  expect(component.text()).toContain('Button clicked: false');

  component.find('button').simulate('click');

  expect(component.text()).toContain('Button clicked: true');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm following [this advice](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086#issuecomment-683438637) and using `mount()` instead of `shallow()`. Obviously, that comes with a performance penalty, so mocking of children is advised.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be mocking `useEffect` to call its first argument when called:

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useEffect: f => f(),
}));
```