# Code coverage missing even when the lines are hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code inside my `useEffect`. This code works fine.

Even tested the functionality via mocking and tests are fine too.

But in terms of `coverage`, it keeps coming up that the following 2 lines are not covered.

```
const check = async () => isValid(); 
check().then((result) => setValid(result));
```

When I try `debug with breakpoints`, I do hit these lines. The `isValid` function is being imported.

That is being tested elsewhere thus I am just mocking the outcome from the `useState` calls.

There is a mandatory 100% code coverage on this project I can't bypass.

Please advice how I could code cover this. Thanks.

P.S: Note that I am using following mock/spy. Without this, `setCookie call` loses coverage too.

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
```

The component being tested

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import isValid from '../helpers/isValid';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';

function AComponent() {
  return (createComponent());
}

export const createComponent = ({data}) => {
  const [valid, setValid] = React.useState(false);
  const [cookie, setCookie] = React.useState(undefined);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const check = async () => isValid(); // code coverage missing
      check().then((result) => setValid(result)); // code coverage missing
    }
    setCookie(!!Cookies.get('my-cookie')); // no issue with code coverage
  }, []);

  if (cookie) {
    return <A/>;
  } else if (valid) {
    return <B/>;
  }
  return <C/>;
};

export default AComponent;
```

These are the tests. The snapshot is as expected showing the 3 different outcomes.

Thus the mocking does work.

Thus looking to see how I could cover those lines even if I need to write a couple of tests

without mocking if theres a way.

```
jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
describe('Test', () => {

  const render = (props) => shallow(
    <AComponent
      {...props}
    />
  );

  it('should render A', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(React, 'useState')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(false)) // mocks valid / setValid
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(true)); // mocks cookie / setCookie
    const renderedModule = render({
        data: {a: 1}
    });
    expect(renderedModule)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

 it('should render B', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(React, 'useState')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(true)) // mocks valid / setValid
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(false)); // mocks cookie / setCookie
    const renderedModule = render({
        data: {a: 1}
    });
    expect(renderedModule)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

 it('should render C', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(React, 'useState')
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(false)) // mocks valid / setValid
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => realUseState(false)); // mocks cookie / setCookie
    const renderedModule = render({
        data: {a: 1}
    });
    expect(renderedModule)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
}
```

Comment: Not remotely helpful but: [The Dangerous Myth of 100% Code Coverage](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-dangerous-myth-of-100-code-coverage-42d0e3ad83f3).

Comment: @Andy Read it before and agree too. Too bad can't be arguing with the rule setters back here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to test the behavior of the component instead of implementation. You'd better not mock the React `useEffect`, `useState` hooks. For example, `useState` is more than just a return value, it has many internal implementations, and improper mocks can change its functionality.

`useEffect` hook is not supported by enzyme `shallow` rendering. See [issue#2086](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086) and [Testing a component that uses useEffect using Enzyme shallow and not mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164027/testing-a-component-that-uses-useeffect-using-enzyme-shallow-and-not-mount). So we have to use `mount`.

E.g.

`index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import isValid from './helpers/isValid';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';

function AComponent(props) {
  return createComponent(props);
}

export const createComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [valid, setValid] = React.useState(false);
  const [cookie, setCookie] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const check = async () => isValid();
      check().then((result) => setValid(result));
    }
    setCookie(!!Cookies.get('my-cookie'));
  }, []);

  if (cookie) {
    return <A />;
  } else if (valid) {
    return <B />;
  }
  return <C />;
};

export default AComponent;
```

`./helper/isValid.js`:

```js
export default async () => false;
```

`A.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>a</div>;
```

`B.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>b</div>;
```

`C.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>c</div>;
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React from 'react';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
import C from './C';
import AComponent from './';
import isValid from './helpers/isValid';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

jest.mock('./helpers/isValid');

const whenStable = async (wrapper) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    wrapper.update();
  });
};

describe('71289768', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should render A', () => {
    jest.spyOn(Cookies, 'get').mockReturnValue('sid:abc123');
    const wrapper = mount(<AComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(A).exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
  test('should render B', async () => {
    isValid.mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
    const wrapper = mount(<AComponent data />);
    await whenStable(wrapper);
    expect(wrapper.find(B).exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
  test('should render C', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<AComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(C).exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71289768/index.test.jsx (8.954 s)
  71289768
    ✓ should render A (39 ms)
    ✓ should render B (32 ms)
    ✓ should render C (6 ms)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |   94.59 |      100 |   81.82 |     100 |                   
 71289768         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  A.jsx           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  B.jsx           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  C.jsx           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
  index.jsx       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 71289768/helpers |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
  isValid.js      |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.457 s
```

Note: When calling an async function inside `useEffect` hook and setting the state, you need to wait for the component render to complete. The `whenStable` function does the trick.

Comment: Can we use shallow or mount is a must? Cos it doesn't do the coverage with shallow and with mount it is failing due to calls to nested components.

Comment: Could I check what was the update. I am mainly looking at should render B. It seems to be the same. Issue is with using mount. Wondering if shallow should work too. Cos shallow doesn't.